# Passing table name as a parameter in SSRS dataset definition

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

OK so I'm trying to add a dataset that can dynamically create a table name and accept several other parameters to retrieve the desired output. The following is my dataset query -

```
declare @cmd nvarchar(max)

select @cmd = 'select at.LocationID, at.LocationName as Location, er.company_name as Company, er.BranchShortCode as Branch, er.Department_Name as Department , 
at.UniqueEmpID, er.EmpName , er.Designation_Name ,convert(date,at.AttendanceDate) as AttendanceDate, at.StatusCode, 
substring(convert(varchar(20),convert(time,at.InTime)),1,8) as InTime, substring(convert(varchar(20),convert(time,at.OutTime)),1,8) as OutTime, 
at.ShiftFName as ShiftName, at.BeginTime as ShiftStartTime, at.EndTime  as ShiftEndTime
from ' + @TableName + ' as at inner join EmployeeAllDetail_Rpt er on at.UniqueEmpID = er.UniqueEmpID
where LocationID in (@LocationID) and er.company_id in (@Company_ID) 
and er.branch_id in (@Branch_ID) and er.dept_id in (@dept_ID) 
and convert(date,at.AttendanceDate) between convert(date,@FromDate) and convert(date,@ToDate)
and DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,@FromDate,103),convert(date,@ToDate,103)) <= 7
order by at.LocationID, er.company_name, er.BranchShortCode, er.Department_Name, at.AttendanceDate'

exec (@cmd)
```

Now @TableName is a variable internal parameter based on @FromDate, wherein it extracts month and year to form the table name like say "Attendance_072020".

@LocationID/@CompanyID/@Branch_ID/@Dept_ID & @FromDate/@ToDate are several other parameters.

When I try to refresh fields using above query I get a "@LocationID" must be declared error.

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can help or guide me in the right direction. If this can't be achieved using SSRS I would be really thankful if anyone can briefly show how I could design a stored procedure to accomplish the same.

UPDATE: This is my code block now which I'm using in my report -

```
DECLARE @TableNamesql NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Params NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableName NVARCHAR(128),
        @FromDate date,
        @ToDate date,
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10),
        @LocationID int,
        @Company_ID int,
        @Branch_ID int,
        @dept_ID int;

SET @Params = N'@LocationID int, @Company_ID int, @Branch_ID int, @dept_ID int, @FromDate date, @ToDate date';
--PRINT @Params


SET @TableNamesql = N'select @TableName = Tablename from (' + @CRLF +
                    N'select case when datepart(month,@FromDate) < 10 then ' + '''hrms_Attendance_0''' + ' + cast(datepart(month,@FromDate) as varchar) + ' + @CRLF +
                    N'cast(datepart(year,@FromDate) as varchar) ' + @CRLF +
                    N'else ' + '''hrms_Attendance_''' + ' + cast(datepart(month,@FromDate) as varchar) + cast(datepart(year,@FromDate) as varchar) end as Tablename)t';
--PRINT @TableNamesql

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @TableNamesql,N'@FromDate DATE, @TableName nvarchar(128) OUTPUT',@FromDate = @FromDate, @TableName = @TableName OUTPUT
--PRINT @TableName

SET @SQL = N'SELECT at.LocationID,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.LocationName AS Location,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.company_name AS Company,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.BranchShortCode AS Branch,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.Department_Name AS Department,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.UniqueEmpID,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.EmpName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.Designation_Name,' + @CRLF +
           N'       CONVERT(date, at.AttendanceDate) AS AttendanceDate,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.StatusCode,' + @CRLF +
           N'       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(time, at.InTime)), 1, 8) AS InTime,' + @CRLF +
           N'       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(time, at.OutTime)), 1, 8) AS OutTime,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.ShiftFName AS ShiftName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.BeginTime AS ShiftStartTime,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.EndTime AS ShiftEndTime' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' at' + @CRLF + 
           N'  INNER JOIN EmployeeAllDetail_Rpt er ON at.UniqueEmpID = er.UniqueEmpID' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE LocationID IN (@LocationID)' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND er.company_id IN (@Company_ID)' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND er.branch_id IN (@Branch_ID)' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND er.dept_id IN (@dept_ID)' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND at.AttendanceDate >= @FromDate' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND at.AttendanceDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate)' + @CRLF + 
           N'  AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate) <= 7' + @CRLF +
           N'ORDER BY at.LocationID,' + @CRLF +
           N'         er.company_name,' + @CRLF +
           N'         er.BranchShortCode,' + @CRLF +
           N'         er.Department_Name,' + @CRLF +
           N'         er.UniqueEmpID,' + @CRLF +
           N'         at.AttendanceDate;';
--PRINT @SQL

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @LocationID, @Company_ID, @Branch_ID, @dept_ID, @FromDate, @ToDate;
'''
```

Comment: The fact you want to do this suggests have you have overall design flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, the fact that you need a query like this suggests you have a design flaw. If you have multiple tables all with the same definition, then this likely means you have a denormalised design and need to really be fixing that.

As for answering the question, this is why you shouldn't be using `EXEC (@SQL)`; you can't parametrise the statement. Variables/parameters only exist in the scope they are declared in. They will not exist in the dynamic statement, as that is a separate scope. This is why you should always be using a **parametrised** call to `sys.sp_executesql`.

You also need to **safely** inject the value of your dynamic object. This gives you something like the below (*note there are several comments in this code you should be checking and changing as needed*):

```sql
/*
Other pamaraters will have been previously declared, however, I assume the following datatypes:
@TableName sysname
@LocationID int
@Company_ID int
@Branch_ID int
@dept_ID int
@FromDate date
@ToDate date
*/

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @Params nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

--I may have missed some out here, and I have GUESSED data types
SET @Params = N'@LocationID int, @Company_ID int, @Branch_ID int, @dept_ID int, @FromDate date, @ToDate date';

SET @SQL = N'SELECT at.LocationID,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.LocationName AS Location,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.company_name AS Company,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.BranchShortCode AS Branch,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.Department_Name AS Department,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.UniqueEmpID,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.EmpName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       er.Designation_Name,' + @CRLF +
           N'       CONVERT(date, at.AttendanceDate) AS AttendanceDate,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.StatusCode,' + @CRLF +
           N'       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(time, at.InTime)), 1, 8) AS InTime,' + @CRLF +
           N'       SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(20), CONVERT(time, at.OutTime)), 1, 8) AS OutTime,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.ShiftFName AS ShiftName,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.BeginTime AS ShiftStartTime,' + @CRLF +
           N'       at.EndTime AS ShiftEndTime' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' at' + @CRLF + --Guessed Schema
           N'     INNER JOIN EmployeeAllDetail_Rpt er ON at.UniqueEmpID = er.UniqueEmpID' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE LocationID IN (@LocationID)' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND er.company_id IN (@Company_ID)' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND er.branch_id IN (@Branch_ID)' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND er.dept_id IN (@dept_ID)' + @CRLF +
           --Considering I have assumed that @FromDate and @ToDate are dates, there is no need to convert them.
           --You should also be using >= and < logic here, so I assume what you actually want is this:
           N'  AND at.AttendanceDate >= @FromDate' + @CRLF +
           N'  AND at.AttendanceDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate)' + @CRLF + 
           --This seems an odd clause to have in the WHERE.
           --Again, considering I have assumed that @FromDate and @ToDate are dates, there is no need to convert them.
           N'  AND DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate) <= 7' + @CRLF +
           N'ORDER BY at.LocationID,' + @CRLF +
           N'         er.company_name,' + @CRLF +
           N'         er.BranchShortCode,' + @CRLF +
           N'         er.Department_Name,' + @CRLF +
           N'         at.AttendanceDate;';

--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend.

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, @Params, @LocationID, @Company_ID, @Branch_ID, @dept_ID, @FromDate, @ToDate; --If I missed any parameters, you need to add these
```

You can use your "best friend" to aid in debugging.

*Note, I highly recommend using whitespace and line breaks as well; as I have done above. Your dynamic statement was impossible to read in the block you posted. Just because a statement is dynamic doesn't mean you should throw formatting out the window.*

I expand more on dynamic SQL and good practices in my article [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).

Comment: Apologies for the late response but thanks this solution helped me a great deal. However though the code runs fine on SQL server it does raise an unknown exception in SSRS. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something clear and obvious.

Comment: As the statement is dynamic, @JaiKumar , SSRS can't run the query without parameters; so can't determine the result set. When you add it as the dataset, it'll ask you for some input parameters; enter some values in that are valid and SSRS will get the definition. Otherwise you'll need to manually define the dataset in SSRS.

Comment: ``SET @TableNamesql = N'select @TableName = Tablename from (' + @CRLF +
N'select case when datepart(month,@FromDate) < 10 then ' + '''hrms_Attendance_0''' + ' + cast(datepart(month,@FromDate) as varchar) + ' + @CRLF +
N'cast(datepart(year,@FromDate) as varchar) ' + @CRLF +
N'else ' + '''hrms_Attendance_''' + ' + cast(datepart(month,@FromDate) as varchar) + cast(datepart(year,@FromDate) as varchar) end as Tablename)t';

Comment: Ok so I'm assigning tablename value to a variable using the above statements, and on refreshing fields I get this error - "The variable name '@TableName' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

Comment: I don't declare `@TableName` in my query, @JaiKumar , I *assume* you have declared it as a parameter (in the SP, report?). If you've added a declare, then that seems to be the problem

Comment: I've updated my original question coz couldn't fit the code in comments. Bear with me I'm a newbie :P

Comment: This feels like we're going onto a new question, @JaiKumar . I'm not answering a new question, or the moved goal posts, when i've already address the original question.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the help.